# import fonts into eclipse to support unicode

Tags: android, eclipse, unicode, fonts

how can i import musica fonts into eclipse to support musical unicode? Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simple one.

create a folder in the root of your project called **`assets/fonts/`** then paste the TTF font file (in this case Verdana.ttf). Then, if you want to apply that font to, say a TextView, do the following:

```
public class FontSampler extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                          "fonts/Verdana.ttf");

    tv.setTypeface(face);
  }
}
```

This example was taken from the ComonsWare book (written by Mark Murphy). You can  [download the full example from GitHub](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fonts/FontSampler/) .

Comment: @bamboolouie glad about ur reply